# Ninject and MVCContrib GridModels

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, mvccontrib-grid

I am sure there has to be an easy way to do this, but I just cant seem to get my head around it.

I am using the MVCContrib Grid control to display a number of grids in a 3 tier application I am working on (ASP.NET MVC3 PL -> BLL -> DAL). I also am using Ninject to automatically inject all my dependencies.

The problem I am having is that I am using a grid model to display grids in my Views like this:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).WithModel(new UserGridModel(Html)).Attributes(id => tableName)
```

and have the corresponding grid model defined:

```
public class UserGridModel : GridModel<User> {

    public UserGridModel(HtmlHelper html)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> userStatuses = /*TODO: GET ALL USER STATUSES*/;            

        Column.For(user => user.ID);
        Column.For(user => html.ActionLink(user.Email, "Edit", new {id = user.ID})).Named(DtoResources.UserDto_Email);
        Column.For(user => user.FirstName);
        Column.For(user => user.LastName);
        Column.For(user => userStatuses[user.StatusID]);
    }
}
```

Now I need to inject a service into this model so it can pull in all of the applicable statuses from the service (BLL) level. Currently just to make sure this would work, I exposed the IKernel in the Bootstrapping code and just IKernel.Get() but I don't think that is the cleanest way to get it. I would use constructor injection, but if I put the IUserStatusService as a parameter in the constructor, I can't figure out how I would get Ninject to inject the correct parameter when I call new UserGridModel(Html) in the view without explicitly using the IKernel there.

I am either missing something or wiring this up all wrong. Either way I'm stuck ... any help? What is the proper way to get an instance of my service through Ninject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the cleanest solution to your problem is to change your controller so that it creates a model that already contains the user status as string so that no convertions is required in the view. I would do as littel as possible in the view and grid model.

Another possibility is to property inject the service to your view an pass it to the grid model. But as I mentioned this way you are introducing logic to your view.

Comment: Thanks Remo. I agree, after looking at it, it makes much more sense to have my controller drop this list into the viewdata/viewmodel when needed.